# Move backwards through Profile/Conversation column history in Tweetdeck?

Tags: tweetdeck

In Tweetdeck, you can view conversations by clicking the `in reply to` portion of tweets.  This opens up a column in overlay.  This overlay column is also used when you open up a user's profile.  The column can be closed by clicking the `X` in the upper right of the column or by pressing `Esc`.

Let's say that I've opened a user's profile in this overlay column.  Reading this user's recent tweets, one of them is a reply, so I click `in reply to` which replaces the contents of the overlay column with the conversation details.

If I close this column, then the overlay column disappears.  **Is there anyway that I can navigate back through the history of the column to get to the user's profile again?**  Often times I find that I want to continue reading what I had there, but I have to start at the very beginning of the process to get back to where I was which is more than slightly annoying, especially if I was several levels in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> . Is there anyway that I can navigate back through the history of the column to get to the user's profile again

I'm afraid there's no way currently. Tweetdeck always fetches the entire conversation every time you click on `in_reply_to`. You could post it [as a feature request](http://support.tweetdeck.com/categories/2022-desktop), though.

Comment: *Tweetdeck always fetches the entire conversation every time you click on in_reply_to.*  That's fine, I just want to be able to move backwards through history.

Comment: @rchern There is no history, per se. The same is used for all, so the previous state gets discarded